# vim select function in python

Tags: python, vim

I am new to vim and recently I learned that it is possible to select a function in c with `vip`, and I was wondering if there is a way to do it with functions in python

keep in mind that function can contain different indentation levels  for example

```
def func():
    pass

    if 1 > 2:
        pass
```

and that I can't use any plugins

Answer (score 1):

`vip` is `v`, followed by `ip`:

- `v` enters visual mode,
- `ip` is a text object that expands the selection to cover the current "paragraph".

It *could* be used to visually select a function in any language with functions, maybe, ***if that function satisfies Vim's definition of "paragraph"***. But that is a big "if", so `vip` is as far from being a "select function" silver bullet as it can be.

See `:help v` and `:help ip`.

Now, the way text objects like `ip` work is that they essentially locate a known landmark in one direction (a blank line in the case of `ip`) and then look for a matching one in the other direction.

Given that (simplified) description, it would be relatively easy to imagine a custom pseudo-text object for a Ruby function:

```
def say_hello(name)
    var = "Hello, " + name

    return var
end
```

because its boundaries are clearly defined.

But Python functions:

```
def func():
    pass

    if 1 > 2:
        pass
```

don't have well defined boundaries and there is not a single built-in text object that is able to cover such a case.

You will need third-party help for that:

- https://github.com/jeetsukumaran/vim-pythonsense
- https://github.com/bps/vim-textobj-python
- probably others…

Comment: actually, I can't use any plugins for this, maybe there is a way by using custom commands in .vimrc or predefined macros

Comment: Nonsense. If you can edit your `vimrc`, then you can use plugins.

Comment: I will re·phrase it, I am not allowed to use plugins

Comment: There is no fundamental difference between a half-understood snippet copied from a SO answer and a plugin. If you are allowed to add stuff to your `vimrc`, then not allowing you to install plugins makes no sense. Anyway, just take a look at the code in the linked plugins: what you want happens to be one of the hard things in Vim.